# HOTween OnComplete(MyFunction) not being triggered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code:

```
void FunctionName( Vector3 pos, Vector3 targetPos){

    Vector3[] path = new Vector3[] { 
       pos, 
       new Vector3(targetPosition.x, ((directionDown) ? 100 : -300), 0), 
       new Vector3(targetPosition.x, targetPosition.y + ( ( directionDown ) ? 300 : -500 ), 0) 
    };

    Transform starEffect = starEffectObject.transform;
    starEffect.localPosition = pos;

    HOTween.To(starEffect, 
               1.5f, 
               new TweenParms()
                   .Prop(
                       "localPosition", 
                       new PlugVector3Path(path, EaseType.Linear, true)
                   )
                   .OnComplete(TriggerFunction)
    );
}

private void TriggerFunction() {
    Debug.Log("asd");
}
```

My issue is that `OnComplete(TriggerFunction)` is not triggered as indicated in the [HOTween documentation](http://hotween.demigiant.com/documentation.html#tweenparms)

However, if I replace `OnComplete(TriggerFunction)` with `OnStart(TriggerFunction)`, everything works fine.

Can someone please assist me with this issue? Or please send me in the right direction for an alternate solution to achieving the trigger of the `TriggerFunction` at the end of the tween.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I manage to trick it with:

```
StartCoroutine(TriggerFunction(0.2f));

IEnumerator TriggerFunction(float delay) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    Debug.Log("asd");
}
```

But I feel like there is a better cleaner solution for doing this.

Comment: It could be a bug. well atleast you found a hack for it.
is there a reason you don't use DoTween ("Hotween v2")

Comment: I did not even know there was one :) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Can you double check about the function? I have just checked with the same code you have written and OnComplete seems to be working for me in Unity2018.2. Try deleting and reimporitng package?

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: @killer_mech it looks like I was using an outdated version of HOTween that came with another package I was using. After updating it everything works like a charm.

Comment: @killer_mech if you add an answer with that suggestion, I will gladly award you the bounty.

Comment: @cornel.raiu ok. I have added it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the comment thread I believe the asset OP was using which came up bundled with HOTween must have its issues which blocked the OnComplete from callback.

> it looks like I was using an outdated version of HOTween that came
>   with another package I was using. After updating it everything works
>   like a charm.

As I have imported HOTween in Unity2018.2 from asset store and tested the OnComplete callback still works so the issue is because of outdated/modified HOTween plugin which OP was using.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used HOTween, but judging from the documentation it seems to be looking for a function with a different signature.

when you call

```
.OnComplete(TriggerFunction)
```

it is likely looking for a callback function with no parameters 
   private void TriggerFunction()

If you were to call
    .OnComplete(TriggerFunction, 1,2,3)
then you could use the function with the single parameter 
  private void TriggerFunction(TweenEvent data)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is only a typo from a different test I did. Sorry for that. I tested it in the no params and with params and it seems I copied mixed code here. Updating it now

Comment: ah ok. Is there a reason you have to set the easing in both the plugin line and with function chaining?

Comment: residue again :) The thing is that with OnStart() or OnUpdate() or whatever it all works. So that is not really relevant

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is maybe the stareffect object or the object that code lives in gets destroyed before the tween finishes?